# Checking if a marker is in the current visible area

Tags: javascript, openlayers

When a marker is clicked and if it is not on the current visible area, I'm want to do something.

I'm trying with this but it's doing it wrong cause its considering markers I cannot see inside the area. Can't figure out what's wrong here. Thanks!

```
var marker_is_visible = this.map.getExtent().containsLonLat (new OpenLayers.LonLat(marker.x, marker.y)) 
if (!marker_is_visible) {
     // Reset view
}
```

Comment: I am missing something here, how can it be clicked if it isn't visible in the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there's a standard function `onScreen()` for this purpose; check it out [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Marker-js.html#OpenLayers.Marker.onScreen).

Answer (score 0):

Think, your `marker.x` and `marker.y` are not latitude and longitude but coordinates of map position of marker. Try to check `x < 0 || y < 0 || x > mapWidth || y > mapHeight`